# Get the style of the old you tube playlist video player

Tags: flash, video, youtube, playlist, video-player

A client of mine want this kind of player to show off his you tube canal:
http://www.youtube.com/cp/vjVQa1PpcFO47iV4yCXKs3uwpqfv-OzC7leA9cug63Q=

He really want a video player where the playlist appears on mouseover, with the two arrows back and follow navigation,

But the problem is this is the old YouTube player and the new YouTube API doesn't allow this kind of effects (how it shows the playlist on mouseover), the playlist just show up on clicking the button playlist, and the arrows disappeared

If you have any idea how I could reproduce this kind of effect in flash. Fead with a dynamic content, in this case a specific you tube canal,

If you know some free flash players able to do this or know the trick to get back an old playlist YouTube viewer like the link I've left I would be very very grateful,